# PDF Generation in Swift Playground

Tags: swift, pdf-generation, swift-playground

Is it possible to create a PDF file using a swift playground?
I'm writing an application that auto generates one out of an array of chosen objects, but it's quickly become a pain to go through the process to check every change I make.

I'm not sure how Playground works in terms of document directories or anything as I've only ever used it for documentation.

Is it possible to do this?

EDIT:

So I've managed to get a PDF to generate from playground by using the directory `NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true)`

I've put a web view into playground to try and preview it but no result.  Is there another way in realtime in the playground?

The web view is loading the request with the correct URL as I used the same url to navigate to it in Finder but It just shows a blank page being previewed in Playground despite images appearing in the PDF in Finder

Playground file

```
import UIKit

// Properties
var documentDirectories : NSArray = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true)
var documentDirectory : String = documentDirectories[0] as! String
var pdfFileName : String = "bill.pdf"
var pdfPathWithFileName : String = (documentDirectory as NSString).stringByAppendingPathComponent(pdfFileName)
let pageSize : CGSize = CGSize(width: 200, height: 1000)

// Graphics Context
UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToFile(pdfPathWithFileName, CGRectZero, nil)
UIGraphicsBeginPDFPageWithInfo(CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 850, height: 1000), nil)
let context : CGContextRef = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!
let rect : CGRect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: pageSize.width, height: pageSize.height)

// Fill background
CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, UIColor.whiteColor().CGColor)
CGContextFillRect(context, rect)

// Products
CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, UIColor.blackColor().CGColor)

for var i = 0; i < 10; i++ {
   let rect : CGRect = CGRect(x: 100, y: (i * 50), width: 300, height: 50)
   let productName : NSString = "ProductNo\(i)"
   productName.drawWithRect(rect, options: .UsesFontLeading, attributes: nil, context: NSStringDrawingContext.init())

   let imageRect : CGRect = CGRect(x: 20, y: (i*50), width: 50, height: 50)
   let image = UIImage(named: "testImage.png")
   image?.drawInRect(imageRect)
}


// End PDF Context
UIGraphicsEndPDFContext()


// PDF Web Request
let pdfURL = NSURL(string: pdfPathWithFileName)
let request = NSURLRequest(URL: pdfURL!)


// Web View
let webSize = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: pageSize.width, height: pageSize.height)
let webView = UIWebView(frame: webSize)
webView.loadRequest(request)

let scroll : UIScrollView = webView.scrollView

let zoom = webView.bounds.size.width/scroll.contentSize.width
scroll.setZoomScale(zoom, animated: true)
```

Comment: Thanks Eric.  See updated question

Comment: You're welcome. Help us help you by showing some relevant code. People may be able to help but for now the question is a bit vague IMO.

Comment: Was meant to paste in the Playground file before, done it now!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you activate the menu:

> View > Debug Area > Show Debug Area

then you can see in the console:

> Failed to obtain sandbox extension for...

Playgrounds are sandboxed, you can't use them to manipulate files that are external to the Playground own resources and `NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains` is rather useless in this case.

The images (or any files you want to use) have to be in the `Resources` folder of your Playground for you to be able to use them with methods like `UIImage(named:)` or `NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource`.

If you activate menu:

> View > Navigators > Show Project Navigator

You will be able to add your images and files to the Playground's `Resources` folder.

*Note: this Resources folder is actually a link to a folder inside the Playground's autogenerated unique cache folder. You shouldn't try to use its URL directly but go via NSBundle (or else) instead.*

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is what you wanted, but the following is how I import PDF files into Swift Playground for iPad:

First, make an `Image` extension (inspired by Paul Hudson's post: [How to render a PDF to an image](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/core-graphics/how-to-render-a-pdf-to-an-image)):

```
import SwiftUI

// Image(pdf: url)
extension Image {
    
    public init?(pdf url: URL) {
        
        guard 
            let doc  = CGPDFDocument(url as CFURL),
            let page = doc .page(at: 1) 
            else { return nil }
        
        let pageRect = page.getBoxRect(.mediaBox)
        let renderer = UIGraphicsImageRenderer(size: pageRect.size)
        
        let img = renderer.image { ctx in
            UIColor.clear.set()
            ctx.fill(pageRect)
            ctx.cgContext.translateBy(x: 0.0, y: pageRect.size.height)
            ctx.cgContext.scaleBy(x: 1.0, y: -1.0)
            ctx.cgContext.drawPDFPage(page)
        }
        
        self = Image(uiImage: img)
    }
}
```

and then import PDF files into Playground (it works on my iPad, you have to try it yourself if you want to work on Xcode):

[image: import PDF files]

then use the extension directly, for example:

```
import SwiftUI
import PlaygroundSupport

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Image(pdf: #fileLiteral(resourceName: "Card1.pdf"))
            Image(pdf: #fileLiteral(resourceName: "Card3.pdf"))
        }// container
            .padding()
            .shadow(radius: 8)
            .background(Color.gray)
            .cornerRadius(10)
    }
}

PlaygroundPage.current.setLiveView(ContentView())
```

the `#fileLiteral` thing is hidden on the Playground, it actually looks like this:

[image: file literal]

although it looks weird, it works and the result looks like this:

[image: pdf images]

hope it helps.